# Generate unique sequential id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I generate a unique sequential ID (that follows a pattern), each time a record is created? How do I address concurrency issues?

I want this ID to follow a fixed pattern.
e.g.: ABC00001, ABC00002, ABC00003, etc

I am doing this to generate student IDs, and I want student IDs within an institute to to be sequential. There will be multiple institutes using my tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using active record then a unique sequential id (`id`) is already created by default and takes care of all concurrency issues for you. If you need to use it for queries then a separate column might be the way forward, but if you just need to display it in a certain format you could simply define a method on your model like:

```
class MyModel
  def my_unique_id
    "ABC%.5d" % id
  end
end

test = MyModel.create
test.id #=> 1
test.my_unique_id #=> "ABC00001"

test2 = MyModel.create
test2.id #=> 2
test2.my_unique_id #=> "ABC00002"
```

EDIT

Ah, you didn't mention that you needed the identifiers to be sequential within an `Institute`. Are you using PostgreSQL? If so the [sequenced gem](https://github.com/djreimer/sequenced) might be a good bet – it adds an `acts_as_sequence` method which allows you to do this:

```
class Student
  acts_as_sequenced scope: :institute_id, column: :sequential_id
  #...
end
```

If you are not using PostgreSQL you'd need to find a way of dealing with concurrency locks in your database system of choice, as the gem only caters for postgres (see [here](https://github.com/djreimer/sequenced/blob/master/lib/sequenced/generator.rb#L49) for how).

Comment: I am actually doing this to generate student IDs, and I want student IDs within an institute to to be sequential. There will be multiple institutes using my tool. If I use the above approach, then students within an institute are not guaranteed to get sequential IDs.

Comment: @user1175969 if you are using postgres you may be in luck (see my edit). If not you'll need to look into how to lock a table in whichever database system you're using. The sequence gem source code is a good place to look for inspiration though.

Comment: I am using postgres. Thanks so much!